# How to limit the maximum uploads in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload

How should i limit the maximum 5 uploads in a single input file in angular

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile" 
onChange="uploadMultipleFiles($event)" >
```

app.component.ts:

```
uploadMultipleFiles(files) {
  if (files.length > 3) {
   this.alertService.error("length exceeded; files have been truncated");
   let list = new DataTransfer;
   for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    list.items.add(files[i]);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the below code, you can prevent the limit of file upload.

```
filesData(files, event): void {
  
    if (event.target.files.length > 5) {
      alert("Only 5 files allow");

      event.preventDefault();
      event.value = ""; // clear the older value 
    } else {
        //Put your Business logic here
    }
  }
```

Also, pass the $event as an argument to the function on the calling the onChange method.

```
 <input type="file" multiple #file (change)="filesData($event)" />
```

Comment: This is not working... while uploading i need to select 5 files. But i am using multiple it is selecting many files

Comment: Yes it is picked multiple files and it gives as array in return and over there onChange method you need to put the validations

Comment: i have added typescript. please let me know anything was wrong

Comment: Just updated answer please check it

Comment: if i am selecting a single file by multiple times also  i need to upload upto 5 files only

Comment: Then this type of validations you need to put it on backend side with managing flag value and other stuff